# Confusing Unicode phenomenon

Tags: linux, nas, unicode

I have an irritating phenomenon in my home network.
My NAS is a Synology, 3 workstations are Apple based and 1 is Windows 10.
Lately I had a problem copying files using the Apple finder and it croaked when it stumbled upon the directory below.

**Antonín_Dvorák--Symphonien_No._8+No._9-»Aus_der_Neuen_Welt«-(Kubelik)/**

When I looked at it with ***ls -li*** from the command line, I saw 2 directories with apparently the same name but with different inodes.

```
441472264 drwxr-xr-x 2 admin users 4096 Mar  2 15:38 Antonín_Dvorák--Symphonien_No._8+No._9-»Aus_der_Neuen_Welt«-(Kubelik)/
441472320 drwxr-xr-x 2 admin users 4096 Mar  2 15:38 Antonín_Dvorák--Symphonien_No._8+No._9-»Aus_der_Neuen_Welt«-(Kubelik)/
```

The Windows file explorer did show the names slightly differently.
On Linux, they are shown exactly the same.
Some utilities which I tried did not have an issue with the directories, but others did.
Looking at the hex dump with ***ls | od -xc***, I found that the name ***Antonín_Dvorák*** has 2 different Unicode representations for the ***í*** and for the ***á***

```
0000000    6e41    6f74    696e    81cc    5f6e    7644    726f    cc61
          A   n   t   o   n   i 314 201   n   _   D   v   o   r   a 314
0000020    6b81    2d2d    7953    706d    6f68    696e    6e65    4e5f
        201   k   -   -   S   y   m   p   h   o   n   i   e   n   _   N

0000000    6e41    6f74    c36e    6ead    445f    6f76    c372    6ba1
          A   n   t   o   n 303 255   n   _   D   v   o   r 303 241   k
```

I don't know how this has happened, but I suspect that copying or making backups created the mess, because when digging deeper, I found quite a few more items like this in my classical music collection.
Has anybody seen similar problems and can possibly shine more light on this?

Comment: one is in precomposed form and the other is in combined form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Has anybody seen similar problems ...**

Yes

Similar in that two different filenames can appear visually identical.

Not sufficiently similar to help you understand the exact cause of your specific case.

> **and can possibly shine more light on this?**

I think you have probably characterised it correctly.

There are "[normal forms](https://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html)" for Unicode which are intended to reduce this kind of issue.

Software transferring data between dissimilar systems might convert to a normalised form in an attempt to prevent this. In the same way that the File Transfer Protocol (FTP) will change platform-specific line-endings in text files - which can lead to problems. I guess it is possible that any form of change, including normalising, could actually make the problem worse in some circumstances.

---

Related:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/utf8-filenames-and-shell-utilities - which gives clues as to how you can unscramble the mess - though not how to prevent future occurrences.
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/convmv.1.html which is a potentially useful tool that might be available on OSX?

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>        convmv [options] FILE(S) ... DIRECTORY(S)
>
> OPTIONS
>
>
> ...
>
>        --nfc
>            target files will be normalization form C for UTF-8 (Linux etc.)
>
>        --nfd
>            target files will be normalization form D for UTF-8 (OS X etc.).
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification and the useful links.